# Cleansing "\312" from file in emacs

Tags: emacs, data-cleaning

I'm an emacs user, but if I can accomplish on the command line that is acceptable. I've tried a query-replace in emacs, but emacs can't seem to locate the character(s) "\312", I've tried a few permutations.

How do I go about cleansing these from my file? Sample data is below:

```
7/30/15 0:15,1781,4,Zima Blue and Other Stories ,2006,\312Alastair Reynolds
7/30/15 0:23,1782,5,Zimmerman's Algorithm ,2000,\312S. Andrew Swann
7/30/15 0:27,1783,1,"Zimmermann Telegram, the ",1958,\312Barbara W. Tuchman
7/30/15 0:47,1784,2,"Zinzin Road, the ",1966,\312Fletcher Knebel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not four characters: `\312`. That is a single character, represented as the octal digits `312` because Emacs could not display that character otherwise. See the Emacs manual, node [Text Display](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Display.html).

You *can* use `query-replace` to replace it. Just use `C-q` followed by `312` to insert it in the string to replace.  For example:

```
M-% C-q 312 RET RET RET
```

The first `RET` ends inputting octal digits.  The second `RET` accepts the string (with that single character, `\312`) to replace. The third `RET` accepts the empty string as the replacement.

Comment: Hello Drew - thanks, but I couldn't get the key-combo to work. Everytime I enter M-% it enters the query replace and there's no where for me to type in C-q. Sorry if it sounds dumb, but just not getting it.

Comment: When it enters query-replace it prompts you in the minibuffer (at the bottom of the window) for the text to replace. That's where you type `C-q 312 RET`. You should see `\312` in the minibuffer after you do that. Then `RET` to accept that text to be replaced. Then it prompts you for the text to replace it with. Just make sure there is no text in the minibuffer at that point (it should be empty by default) and hit `RET` to accept that (empty text) as the replacement.

Comment: Then you are queried at each occurrence of `\312` in the buffer, and you hit `y` to confirm its replacement. Or you can hit `!` to replace all occurrences. Before you use `M-%`, position the cursor at the buffer beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity, lets just assume operator error and I'll make this as the proper answer. Thanks.